Is it possible to enable RDP via poking a system drive directly? Corrupted graphics driver
I have a Laptop that briefly shows artefacts on the screen then goes blank before the logon screen.
Its a HP 14-cm0000 laptop and I think the graphics driver is corrupted.
Judging by the disk activity I believe the system is functional under the blank screen.
If I move the mouse the cursor becomes visible but after 5 seconds it snaps back to the centre of the screen.
Also if I press Win-P the blue Project bar appears on the right but displays no text or graphic.
I have tried all safe mode options but receive the same results.
I have tried Auto repair, Bios Diagnostics, SFC, CHKDSK and W10 USB repair but all results are clear.
The system Boots HBCD_PEx64 from USB fine so I presume the hardware is good.
I have tried manually renaming the graphics drivers hoping the system will restore them but no.
So I'm asking if it is possible to enable RDP by poking the host drive from within the Hirons PE Boot environment?
but I'm worried that the corrupt display would be piped to the RDP Client anyways.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly received.
